# server migration and could not connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, centos, server-migration

I have a Centos 5.5 Server and needs to migrate to a new one with 6.6. I have about three websites, a third party application(service). I need to put all these to my new server and host the websites. 
And In the new machine i am not able to connect to mysql, when i try to connect using 
***mysql -u root*** the below error is shown.

**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)**

Please suggest how can i connect with mysql and the migration? I am new to this.

I have tried to change the password using skip grantables and again the result is same.

Comment: Looks like mysql is not running on localhost.

Comment: mysql is running, how to check whether it's running in localhost?

Comment: And i have plesk 11 installed installed in new server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plesk 11 then try to login your mysql shell with the following command

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```